# How to work with translations on a date?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

I am trying to render a translated date coming from an API and I am wondering what's the best way to do it.

The value coming from the API is formatted as "February 13, 2007"
I would love to keep this format for english language but to have "13 Février 2007" for french and "13. Februar 2007" for german.

I tried to `strtotime()` the value when I receive it and `|format_date()` it in twig - it works but the date is printed with the medium date format (`D, m/d/Y - H:i`).

For this medium format, the translation works as expected, in french I see the date formated as `D d/m/Y - H:i` as it is set in `/admin/config/regional/translate`.

But I want `j F Y` for french, `F j, Y` for english, `j. F Y` for german. Drupal core doesn't give this format so I created a custom date-time format for the undefined language with `F j, Y` as value.

The problem is that I can't translate this format from `/admin/config/regional/translate` like it's done for the core date-time formats.

Any clue?